# How to define max.poll.records (SCS with Kafka) over containers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to figure out the poll records mechanism for Kafka over SCS in a K8s environment.

1. What is the recommended way to control `max.poll.records`?
2. How can I poll the defined value?
3. Is it possible to define it once for all channels and then override for a specific channel?
   (referring to [this comment form documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.M1/reference/html/_configuration_options.html#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20repetition%2C%20Spring%20Cloud,channels%2C%20in%20the%20format%20spring.)):

> To avoid repetition, Spring Cloud Stream supports setting values for
> all channels, in the format of
> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.=. The
> following properties are available for Kafka consumers only and must
> be prefixed with
> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings..consumer..")

4. Is this path supported: `spring.cloud.stream.binding.<channel name>.consumer.configuration`?
5. Is this: `spring.cloud.stream.**kafka**.binding.<channel name>.consumer.configuration`?
6. How are conflicts being resolved? Let's say in a case where both `spring.cloud.stream.binding...` and `spring.cloud.stream.**kafka**.binding...` are set?

I've tried all mentioned configurations, but couldn't see in the log what is the **actual** `poll.records` and frankly the documentation is not entirely clear on the subject.

Comment: _couldn't see in the log what is the actual poll.records_ - This sounds like  a logging problem since, by default, `ConsumerConfig` output does show this value

Answer (score 0):

These are the configurations:

1. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records - default if nothing else specified for given channel
2. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings..consumer.configuration.max.poll.records

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).